# Javascript error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a CS:GO betting website and when I try to go to the page 
to withdraw skins or something like that after I verify that i am not a robot using recaptcha I get this error:

> Javascript error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Here is the code :

```
function redeem(){
    var code = $("#promocode").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/redeem?code="+code,
        success:function(data){     
            try{
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(data.success){
                    bootbox.alert("Success! You've received "+data.credits+" credits.");                    
                }else{
                    bootbox.alert(data.error);
                }
            }catch(err){
                bootbox.alert("Javascript error: "+err);
            }
        },
        error:function(err){
            bootbox.alert("AJAX error: "+err);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.$.ajax.success (http://www.gamesnodie.com/template/js/offers.js?v=106:249:29)
at j (http://www.gamesnodie.com/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:27244)
at Object.k.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://www.gamesnodie.com/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:28057)
at x (http://www.gamesnodie.com/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:85993)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (http://www.gamesnodie.com/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:90047)
```

Network tab results:
http://prntscr.com/b1pao5

Comment: Check what the value of `data` is in your success function. It probably isn't what you expect.

Comment: What is the raw response you get? (Hint: Check that in Networks tab)

Comment: In the Network tab, you need to click on the request to see the details of the response body.

Comment: I can't find the request button that you mean ... I am kinda noobie with java script and so on cause my actual developer is now gone so I am all by myself xD.

Comment: You have to see the response data, it's not matching JSON encode. Put a console.log(data) and comment out data = JSON.parse(data). Check the console and see what kind of response your are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by generating a recaptcha key and adding it to the config file.
After that the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please post in your question the JSON you are receiving from the server.

This issue could be related to a malformed JSON, or a wrong Header Content Type of your request, which actually should be as "application/json" as "Content-type" for JSON.